# MySQL query to append key:value to JSON string

Tags: mysql, sql

My table has a column with **a JSON string that has nested objects** (so a simple REPLACE function cannot solve this problem) . For example like this: `{'name':'bob', 'blob': {'foo':'bar'}, 'age': 12}`. What is the easiest query to append a value to the end of the JSON string?  So for the example, I want the end result to look like this: `{'name':'bob', 'blob': {'foo':'bar'}, 'age': 12, 'gender': 'male'}` The solution should be generic enough to work for any JSON values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this

```
UPDATE table SET table_field1 = CONCAT(table_field1,' This will be added.');
```

**EDIT:**

I personally would have done the manipulation with a language like PHP before inserting it. Much easier. Anyway, Ok is this what you want? This should work providing your json format that is being added is in the format `{'key':'value'}`

```
 UPDATE table
 SET col = CONCAT_WS(",", SUBSTRING(col, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(col) - 1),SUBSTRING('newjson', 2));
```

Comment: I think this would just concat the value to the end of the string. I need to add it within the json. For example, your solution would turn `{'abc':'123'}` to `{'abc':123'}This will be added.` I need the a json string like `{'abc':'123', 'key':'value'}`

Comment: Ok I updated my answer. It seemed to work for me with the example you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) function to achieve this

```
UPDATE table
SET column = REPLACE(column, '{\'name\':\'bob\', \'blob\': {\'foo\':\'bar\'}, \'age\': 12}', '{\'name\':\'bob\', \'blob\': {\'foo\':\'bar\'}, \'age\': 12, \'gender\': \'male\'}')
```

Take care to properly escape all quotes inside json

Upon you request of nested json, i think you can just remove last character of the string with [`SUBSTRING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) function and then append whatever you need with `CONCAT`

```
UPDATE table
SET column = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(column, 0, -1), 'newjsontoappend')
```

Comment: That's a nice solution but I need a query that works with any json value. I don't know the json value in the column beforehand.

Comment: @Glide If you just need to append something at the end you could  replace final bracket `}` with `yournewjsondata }`

Comment: the thing is, there are nested json objects inside the json string. so replace `}` WITH `myjsondata` would turn this `{'name':'bob', 'blob': {'foo':'bar'}, 'age': 12}` to `{'name':'bob', 'blob': {'foo':'bar','jsonkey':'jsonvalue'}, 'age': 12, 'jsonkey':'jsonvalue'}`. I only want to append it to the very end of the json string.

Answer (score 0):

modify Jack's answer. Works perfectly even column value is empty on first update.

```
update table
 set column_name = case when column_name is null or column_name ='' 

 then "{'foo':'bar'}"
 else CONCAT_WS(",", SUBSTRING(column_name, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(column_name) - 1),SUBSTRING("{'foo':'bar'}", 2))
 end
```