# How to Append JSON Object in already created object in mysql json document

Tags: mysql, node.js

My object is

```
{
"name":"Testing",
"id": "hcig_3fe7cb00-e936-11e6-af69-a748c8cc89ad",
"belongsTo": {
    "id": "69616d26-c3bb-405c-8c84-c51c091524b2",
    "name": "test"
},
"locatedAt": {
    "id": "49616d26-c3bb-405c-8c84-c51c091524b2",
    "name":"Test"
}  }
```

I want to merge one more object like

```
"obj":[{
    "a": 123
 }}
```

With the help of **JSON_MERGE** in mysql document store i am able to add object.
But it looks likes

```
{
"name":"Tester",
"id": "hcig_3fe7cb00-e936-11e6-af69-a748c8cc89ad",
"belongsTo": {
    "id": "69616d26-c3bb-405c-8c84-c51c091524b2",
    "name": "test"
},
"locatedAt": {
    "id": "49616d26-c3bb-405c-8c84-c51c091524b2",
    "name":"Test"
},{
    "obj":[{
    "a": 123
 }]
}}
```

I want my object to be as

```
{
  "name": "Tester",
  "id": "hcig_3fe7cb00-e936-11e6-af69-a748c8cc89ad",
  "belongsTo": {
     "id": "69616d26-c3bb-405c-8c84-c51c091524b2",
     "name": "test"
  },
 "locatedAt": {
   "id": "49616d26-c3bb-405c-8c84-c51c091524b2",
   "name": "Test"
 },
 "obj": [{
    "a": 123
}]}
```

Any idea on how to add object as above manner using JSON Functions in mysql ??

Comment: You may try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099089/mysql-query-to-append-keyvalue-to-json-string

Comment: @kawadhiya21 :- Yes that is working, but i have syntax like :-     UPDATE device SET doc = CONCAT_WS(",", SUBSTRING(doc, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(doc) - 1),SUBSTRING('{"a":"{"b":"123"}"}', 2)) where id = '6aa02850-ed01-11e6-af3b-9d6a036cc416';  For this it is not working .

Answer (score 0):

Use lodash for a recursive deep copy - https://lodash.com/

```
lodash.merge(targetObj, sourceObj);
```

Or if you have programmatic access:

```
targetObj.obj = sourceObj;
```